# Spring AOP - Pointcut Not working

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I had created a pointcut. But it is not working. 
    Please assist me on the below code. 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="customerBo" class="com.mkyong.customer.bo.impl.CustomerBoImpl" />

<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="logAspect" class="com.mkyong.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
```

https://pastebin.com/Qi0cJkJJ

Comment: Please refer to pastebin link for the entire code: (https://pastebin.com/Qi0cJkJJ)

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any sense to XML-configure the aspect bean as `LoggingAspect` and then call your aspect class `MyAspect`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the pointcut definition. You use

```
 @Pointcut("within(com.mkyong.customer.bo.*)")
 public void checkMyDetails() {}
```

but to define a pointcut in a package and all its subpackages (in your case: the implementation package), the syntax would be

```
 @Pointcut("within(com.mkyong.customer.bo..*)")
 public void checkMyDetails() {}
```

Note the two dots: `bo..*` instead of `bo.*`